# Scaffold in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have my code setup as below:

What would I need to change here to not have to add the @SuppressLint?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `paddingValues` on next content, it is there exactly to calculate the correct screen display for the content to come in the compose tree.

If you don't use it, your screen will appear behind scafold elements, like the topbar or the bottombar.

Content without `innerPadding` set:

[image: without innerPadding]

Content with `innerPadding` set:

[image: with innerPadding]

Here is an example of how i use it:

```
{ innerPadding ->
            NavHost(
                navController,
                startDestination = startDestination.route,
                Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
            ) {
                currentScreen = navigationItems.find {
                    it.route == currentDestination?.route
                } ?: startDestination
                composable(Screen.NotesList.route) {
                    NotesListScreen(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(horizontal = MaterialTheme.spacing.medium)
                    )
                }
                composable(Screen.Bin.route) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to remove `@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")` warning then you have to add `PaddingValues` to `content` in Scaffold . you can write like this

```
             Scaffold(
                    topBar = { MyTopBar() }
                ) { paddingValues ->
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
                        // write your content here
                    }
                }
```

Basically `PaddingValues` is to provide padding to the content ( always apply `paddingValues` to parent composable function ).